# Actionbar Up Button Listener

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigationview

I have only one activity in my application which contains navigation view to navigate through 3 fragments.

When I navigate to a fragment I get the hamburger menu icon changed to the up button in the onNavigationItemSelected method like this:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The up button appears well but has no effect yet.

I wanna navigate to the previous fragment in the stack when the button is clicked but I can't get to add a listener to that button.

I've tried using:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

but this is never called. I think it's not called because I have no parent activity in the manifest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call onBackPressed, you should use fragment transaction method to to transact between fragments like I replaced my current fragment with previous fragment using replace method. container is the layout containing the fragments.

```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment); 
     transaction.commit();
```

I hope, it give you some  direction.

```
 if (id == android.R.id.home) {
    //put the code like above here.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is not my question.. I know how to navigate between fragments but where should I put this code? I mean there's no listener or something for the up button in the actionbar

Comment: I edited the answer now. Actually android.R.id.home corresponds to the button you are concerned about.

Comment: I tried this, onOptionsItemSelected is never called

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   Did you put this line of code.